# Not able to assume role via lambda function - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Hi I am having this bizarre problem since yesterday. I have a python module web_token.py when I try to run it manually on pycharm and print request_url it works completely fine and outputs the requested_url. But when I zip my web_token.py and fetch_accounts.py together and upload it to lambda function it gives me following error -

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::5398XXXXXXX:assumed-role/sandbox-amp_sandbox-dev/sandbox-dev-amp_sandbox is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::4540XXXXXXXX:role/AMPSandbox

I even tried giving it FullAdministrativeAccess but still it dosent seem to work. Although I am able to generate requested_url when running the web_token.py in stanalone mode in pycharm. Can someone please provide some guidance will really appreciate it.

Code snippet from

> retrieve_accounts.py

```
import boto3

import web_token


def get_account(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    NameID = "test@orgz.com"
    ManagerEmail = "test1@orgaz.com"
    response = client.scan(
        TableName='Sandbox-Users',
        ScanFilter={
            'NameID': {
                'AttributeValueList': [
                    {
                        'S': NameID,
                    },
                ],
                'ComparisonOperator': 'EQ'
            }
        }
    )
    return web_token.request_url
```

> web_token.py

```
import httplib
import urllib, json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role_object = client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::4540XXXXXXXX:role/AMPSandboxRole",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession"
)

# Step 3: Format resulting temporary credentials into JSON
json_string_with_temp_credentials = '{'
json_string_with_temp_credentials += '"sessionId":"' + assumed_role_object.get("Credentials").get("AccessKeyId") + '",'
json_string_with_temp_credentials += '"sessionKey":"' + assumed_role_object.get("Credentials").get("SecretAccessKey") + '",'
json_string_with_temp_credentials += '"sessionToken":"' + assumed_role_object.get("Credentials").get("SessionToken") + '"'
json_string_with_temp_credentials += '}'

# Step 4. Make request to AWS federation endpoint to get sign-in token. Construct the parameter string with
# the sign-in action request, a 12-hour session duration, and the JSON document with temporary credentials
# as parameters.
request_parameters = "?Action=getSigninToken"
request_parameters += "&SessionDuration=43200"
request_parameters += "&Session=" + urllib.quote_plus(json_string_with_temp_credentials)
request_url = "/federation" + request_parameters

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("signin.aws.amazon.com")
conn.request("GET", request_url)
r = conn.getresponse()
# Returns a JSON document with a single element named SigninToken.
signin_token = json.loads(r.read())

request_parameters = "?Action=login"
request_parameters += "&Issuer=sandbox.com"
request_parameters += "&Destination=" + urllib.quote_plus("https://console.aws.amazon.com/")
request_parameters += "&SigninToken=" + signin_token["SigninToken"]
request_url = "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/federation" + request_parameters
```

UPDATE :
I have two policies attached to sandbox-amp_sandbox-dev role-

**InfraLoggingPolicy[in 5398XXXXXXX]**

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessageBatch"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:131703196249:org-logging-prod",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::em-log-intake-us-east-1-prod/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::em-log-intake-us-west-2-prod/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**sandbox-amp_sandbox-policy-dev[in 5398XXXXXXX]**

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE 2.0
These above policies are from my account number 5398XXXXXXX. I have following role in 4540XXXXXXXX account AMPSandboxRole under which I have following policies

**AssumeRole[in 4540XXXXXXXX]**

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/AMPSandboxRole",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**organizationaccess in [4540XXXXXXXX]**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "organizations:Describe*",
                "organizations:List*",
                "organizations:CreateAccount",
                "organizations:MoveAccount"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "organizations:MoveAccount"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:organizations::454084028794:root/o-eyec2h6qr0/r-ekzh"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "organizations:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:organizations::45xxxxxxxxxx:ou/o-eyec2h6qr0/ou-ekzh-x2xcsupl"
        }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE 3.0
**Trust relationship in 45xxxxxxxxxx**

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::53xxxxxxxxxx:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What are the permissions assigned to the role being used by the Lambda function (`sandbox-amp_sandbox-dev/sandbox-dev-amp_sandbox`)?

Comment: Thanks John for reverting back I have updated the question with the role being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this account with some from AWS team. So whenever assuming role from one account to another we need to explicitly provide access key and secret key of the account to which we are assuming role to. So it should look something like this -

```
sts_connection = boto3.client('sts',
                                  aws_access_key_id="",
                                  aws_secret_access_key="")
```

On providing these details I was finally able to assume role in a different account. Thanks everyone for your guidance and help.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to Edit Trust Relationship and add the Role name which can be trusted. 
Here is an example -

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<<Account-ID>>:role/<Role_Name_to_be_trusted>",
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is one useful link -
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3040

Comment: Do you know why isn't it enough to just add the "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com" as "Principal" (without the role) in the TrustRelationship ?

Comment: I was searching all over to see why Step function failing to call Lambda, your solution fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

The error says:

> User: arn:aws:sts::5398XXXXXXX:assumed-role/sandbox-amp_sandbox-dev/sandbox-dev-amp_sandbox is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::4540XXXXXXXX:role/AMPSandbox

The AWS Lambda function is being executed under the role that you have listed above. It only has permission to call `dynamodb:*`. **It also requires permission to call `AssumeRole`.**

Your policy should be updated to:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PermitDynamoDB",
      "Action": "dynamodb:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "PermitAssumeRole",
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRole"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::4540XXXXXXXX:role/AMPSandboxRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey John sorry for the confusion I should have given you policies from both the accounts I do have sts:AssumeRole in my 4540XXXXXXXX(Please check updated question). Also I tried your solution but this dosent seem to work :(

Comment: So, sandbox-amp_sandbox-dev role is in 5398XXXXXXX account and AMPSandbox role is in 4540XXXXXXXX account.
sandbox-amp_sandbox-dev is trying to assume AMPSandbox role.
As @John Rotenstein said, you should add that policiy to sandbox-amp_sandbox-dev role. As of now AssumeRole policy attached to AMPSandboxRole allows AMPSandboxRole role to assume itself, not sure why you want to do that. Also make sure AMPSandbox's trust policy has the ARN of sandbox-amp_sandbox-dev in it (or the 5398XXXXXXX account).

Comment: "sandbox-amp_sandbox-dev is trying to assume AMPSandbox role." yes correct. I did add' {
      "Sid": "PermitAssumeRole",
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRole"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::4540XXXXXXXX:role/AMPSandboxRole"
    }' in sandbox-amp_sandbox-policy-dev but its not working. Also AMPSandbox's trust policy does have account 5398xxxxxxxx in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the Principal entry in your trust rlationship policy document:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PermitAssumeRole",
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRole"
      ],
       "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "dynamodb.amazonaws.com",
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::4540XXXXXXXX:role/AMPSandboxRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

> **Trust policy** is a document in JSON format in which you define who is allowed to assume the role. This trusted entity is included in the policy as the **principal** element in the document.

So your Trust Relationship policy document should include in the *Principal* element the AWS resource you are expecting to assume the role

Comment: Hey Siomes I do have Principal element in the Trust policy of 4540XXXXXXXX. I have now updated the question with the trust policy